# How to move a CAShapeLayer with finger move without delay

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

currently im learning in the playgrounds(single view) mode and i want to move a CAShapeLayer with my finger, but currently it only works with a delay. How can I solve the problem ?

**a little example of the variable in my enumeration**

```
var layer: CAShapeLayer{
    switch self {
    case .rectangle:

        let rectangle = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 60, y: 250, width: 250, height: 350))


        let rect = CAShapeLayer()
        rect.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 350)
        rect.path = rectangle.cgPath
        rect.fillColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        return rect
```

**and the touchesmoved method code**

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    guard let location = touches.first?.location(in: self.view) else {return}

    currentlayer?.position = location

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that what you're seeing is the implicit animation that happens when you change the property of a "standalone" layer. In other words, each time that you're updating the position the layer is doing a quick (but not instant) animation from the previous value to the new value.

To avoid this and have the layer update to the new position without an implicit animation you can change the position within a transaction that disables actions (a more general term for animations in Core Animation).

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
// Changes to the layer within this transaction won't have implicit animations
yourLayer.position = newPosition
CATransaction.commit()
```